# Call a parent's parent method without calling the parent's method. parent::parent::method()?

Tags: extensions, overrides, inheritance

I have an extension that has a block class that extends

```
Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar
```

The extension has its own `getPagerHtml()`, which calls `parent::getPagerHtml()` at the end.

I need to make some modifications to this method in my extension, so I did a rewrite of the class in my own module, extended the class, and adding my own `getPagerHtml()` to it. The problem is in my class rewrite here, I need to call `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar::getPagerHtml()` without calling the extension's `getPagerHtml()`. I basically need to do something like `parent::parent::getPagerHtml()`

Obviously I can't modify the files in the extension. What would be the best approach to accomplish this?

Comment: This is the best answer for a `parent::parent::method()` workaround > https://stackoverflow.com/a/8212262/292408

Answer (score 4):

Just call:

```
Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Toolbar::getPagerHtml()
```

You cannot call `parent::parent`, in PHP, and then in Magento, you can use the static syntax to call the instatiated parent of your parent class.

So, if you have:

```
class A {
  public function myMethod() {
    return 4;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  public function myMethod() {
    return parent::myMethod() + 1;
  }
}
```

And you want to careate class "C" directly calling method on A, you can:

```
class C extends B {
  public function myMethod()
  {
     return A::myMethod() * 2;
  }
}
```

Class A will return "4", class B will return "5", class C will return "8".

Hope it helps.

Comment: Since PHP 5.4, this will cause a STRICT warning, and should be discouraged. please refer to this question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9693/calling-grandparent-class-in-magento-class-inheritance

Comment: @ProxiBlue No, it does not, I'm using it all the time: https://3v4l.org/hGZ2l

Comment: I use it quite often and I never got warnings, also Magento itslef uses it. I'll deep check it.

Comment: Interesting. Back when i asked the question, this was the case. I will look at this again. Things may have changed. Prior to that i used the means described extensively myself.